# Folder Permissions in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, security

I'm trying to securely share a folder across two computers on a relatively public network.  However, I'm a bit confused on how permissions work and was hoping for some clarification between the following so I don't accidentally make something public I don't want.

When you right-click a folder and go to properties, what is the difference between

1. Sharing Tab -> 'Share...' button -> List of users and permissions there
2. Sharing Tab -> 'Advanced Sharing...' button -> 'Permissions' button -> List of users and permissions there
3. Security Tab -> List of users and permissions there

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Share and Advanced Sharing permissions are different views of the same thing.  Obviously, Advanced Sharing has some more advanced options, (like offline availability), I don't have a machine with simple sharing enabled so I cant give a definitive list.

The permissions on the security tab apply to anyone accessing the files, it doesn't matter if they are accessing the file locally or through a network share.  The Share permissions apply to users trying to access the share.  Access to file is only gained if both the share permissions and the normal file permissions allow it.

Share permissions can be used to setup very complex permissions.  I would suggest leaving the share permissions *fairly* open.  I don't know how many users you are giving access to or if they require read or modify permissions, but I would suggest granting the Authenticated Users group the appropriate permissions.

You should also be aware that by default, the windows local security policy will prevent users who don't have a password from accessing files via a network share.

Comment: But I seem to be able to maintain two independent lists in the Share and Advanced Sharing views...

Comment: Also... I kept a user on the 'Security' tab, but removed them from the 'Share' tab... and when the user tried to locally access the folder on the physical computer they got an access denied error.  I'm truly perplexed by this security system.

Comment: You can maintain two seperate lists.  Removing a user from the share tab shouldn't stop a user from accessing the folder locally, unless they are using the UNC path.

Comment: The 'Security" tab governs local access, but the 'Share' tab governs network access.

Comment: sort of. the security tab controls ALL access to the file. The share tab places extra restriction on access to files when the access is over the network. you cant grant access to a file by only granting access to the share.